# Get first mapped result from array

Tags: swift, algorithm

I have an array of functions like

```
let array = [(Int) -> T?, (Int) -> T?, (Int) -> T?,...]
```

I need to get first **non nil T value** from array and I want 1 iteration for this task (O(n) will be the worst complexity). Anybody has neat ideas without for loops?

Comment: You want something like `first(where:)` that doesn't return the array element but instead returns the result of the function call if it's non-nil. There's no simple way to do it in Swift currently so your best bet is to use a `for` loop and break when you find the value you want.

Comment: I know I want something like that. And I don't want for loop cause I'm looking for more neat way of doing that

Comment: You can still use first(where:) and execute the returned function again. Or use a for loop …

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible at all. I'd suggest to write your own version of `firstCompactMapped(where:)` which a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, there's no ready-made way to do this in Swift, so you have to at least implement *something* that uses a `for` loop.

If you want appearances at the call-site to look functional and not use a `for` loop, you can make the function extend `Array` like so:

```
extension Array {
    func firstNonNilResult<V, T>(value: V) -> T? where Element == (V) -> T? {
        for element in self {
            if let t = element(value) {
                return t
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}

var array = [(Int) -> String?]()

func f(_ i: Int) -> String? {
    print("called f() with \(i)")
    return nil
}

func g(_ i: Int) -> String? {
    print("called g() with \(i)")
    return i == 5 ? "found it" : nil
}

array.append(f)
array.append(g)

if let t = array.firstNonNilResult(value: 5) {
    print(t)
}
```

which prints:

```
called f() with 5
called g() with 5
found it
```

Whether or not this has any real-world utility I can't say. I think it's specialized enough that an `Array` extension seems like overkill, but your question is interesting so this is at least a potential solution.